# Search Guard With Spring Data ES

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, search-guard

I followed steps mentioned [here](http://floragunncom.github.io/search-guard-docs/installation.html) to secure my local ES installation using [SearchGuard](http://floragunncom.github.io/search-guard-docs/) (no tag exist for it on SO). Now, it is reachable via Postman only through basic authentication with username password as default `admin/admin`.

Now, I need to allow my Spring Data ES project to be able to access this ES installation.

I tried:

```
Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("path.home", ".")
            .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
            .put("searchguard.ssl.transport.enabled", true)
            .put("searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath", "kirk-keystore.jks")
            .put("searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath", "truststore.jks")
            .put("searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification", false)
            .put("request.headers.sg.impersonate.as", "admin")
            .build();

TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(esSettings)
            .build().addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticsearchHost), elasticsearchPort));

client.prepareGet().putHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64("admin:admin".getBytes())).get();

return client;
```

Added header as suggested [here](https://floragunn.com/transport-client-authentication-authorization/).

But all I get is:

```
[elasticsearch[Meteorite][generic][T#3]] INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport - 
[Meteorite] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][127.0.0.1:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] disconnected
```

I need to get and post new data in ES (2.4.4).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this error ?

Comment: @lives No, for now, the project requirements also changed from using SearchGuard to something else so I did not pursue this furthur.